# Proof involving coprime integers with the same quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, quadratic-residues

Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are coprime positive integers and that the congruences
$x^2 \equiv a \pmod m$, $y^2 \equiv a \pmod n$ have $s$ and $t$ solutions in $x$ and $y$ respectively. Prove that the congruence
$z^2 \equiv a \pmod{mn}$ has $st$ solutions.

Not sure how to really go about proving this.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.